# Get all threaded comments from Bitbucket API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I'm utilizing Bitbucket Server's REST API 1.0 to grab all activities on a pull request using the following endpoint: `/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests/{pullRequestId}/activities`.

My issue is that I'm unable to grab all of the threaded comments. Currently, I'm checking if a user has commented by grabbing the `action` key and seeing if it has a value of `COMMMENTED`. However, if there is a threaded comment then the parent comment has a `comments` array. If that threaded comment also has a threaded comment then there is another `comments` array.

What is the easiest way to grab *all* comments - threaded or not - on the pull request with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the language you use for calling the APIs but if you're in shell you can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the json using this query to build the json object however you need

```sh
curl ... | jq '[ .. | objects | with_entries(select(.key | contains("text"))) | select(. != {}) ]'
```